# How to use table name transforms on Kafka JDBC sink connector?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created few topics using kafka postgres source connector. Their names are as below:

```
server1.public.table1
server1.public.table2
server1.public.table3
```

I am using JDBC sink connector to load this data to postgres on different location. I want postgres tables to be created with name "table1","table2" and "table3".

I used below propertied in sink.json file

```
"topics.regex": "server1.public.(.*)",  
"transforms": "route",
"transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
"transforms.route.replacement": "$3",
"transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter"
```

but are not working. How can i pass the output from above transforms to "table.name.format"?

Or is there any another method to do that?

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? The connector has to show some errors in its status.

Comment: @TonyStark  ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: \"server1.public.table1\"\n.   This is the error. i thik it directly using topic name server1.public.table1 for creating table in postgres.

Comment: after doing all above transforms on topic name, how can i pass output("table1") to "topic.name.format"?

Comment: did you find any answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time but I ran into the same issue as you.
It worked for me with almost the same regex like yours but with just one backslashes.

```
([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)
```

I recommend using [regex editor](https://regex101.com/) to see if it matches! I hope this will help anyone since it's been 2 years without an answer